# copy from whole external worksheet to worksheet in mainbook

Tags: excel, vba

This code works up through the paste into sheet 2 - I can switch over to the new open workbook and see that it is in copy mode but cannot get it to paste into Sheet2(Test).  I have tried both "Sheet2" and "Test"  but get

> run time error 9: subscript out of range

see snip below

[image: View]

```
Sub ImportWorksheet999()

    Dim Wb1 As Workbook
    Dim MainBook As Workbook

    'Open All workbooks first:
    Set Wb1 = Workbooks.Open("G:\T\TWeir\Prod Ctrl\XML Reports\BDA\BDAREPORTtest.xlsx")
    Set MainBook = ActiveWorkbook

    'Now, copy what you want from wb1:
    Wb1.Sheets("BDA Report").Cells.Copy
    'Now, paste to Main worksheet:
    MainBook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").PasteSpecial

    'Close Wb's:
    Wb1.Close

End Sub
```

Comment: Once `Wb1` is open, it's the `ActiveWorkbook`, so `Wb1` and `MainBook` are the same...

Comment: The part you've highlighted is the sheet's `CodeName`. In that case, you can skip accessing it as an index of `Sheets(x).Range()` and use the name itself like so `Sheet2.Range()`

Answer (score 1):

```
Set Wb1 = Workbooks.Open("G:\T\TWeir\Prod Ctrl\XML Reports\BDA\BDAREPORTtest.xlsx")
Set MainBook = ActiveWorkbook
```

Opening a file will make it the ActiveWorkbook, so your `Wb1` and `MainBook` both refer to the opened workbook.

Should be

```
Set MainBook = ActiveWorkbook 'or ThisWorkbook if that's where the code is running
Set Wb1 = Workbooks.Open("G:\T\TWeir\Prod Ctrl\XML Reports\BDA\BDAREPORTtest.xlsx")
```